# change searchFunction dynamically

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

context: I'm trying to implement multiples indexes binding to just one searchbox

I have an array of indexes and I want to edit the `searchFunction` of first one.

```js
const indexes = indexNames.map( name => return createAlgoliaIndex(name) )
const main = indexes[0]

main.searchFunction = (helper) => {
  indexes.forEach( (algoliaIndex, index) => {
    if (index === 0)
      return;

    algoliaIndex.helper.setQuery(helper.state.query).search()
  })

  helper.search()
}

createAlgoliaIndexFor(name) {
  return instantsearch({
    indexName: name,
    searchClient
  })
}
```

Basically it doesn't work :(

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently do not have the choice: the `searchFunction` option must be passed at initialization time.

Here's a working example (sorry the code is a bit messy):

```js
const searchClient = algoliasearch('1KCCSVLJHD', '0fb99058412c4776c60725c0fe9b2d7d');

const indexes = ["test", "test2"].map((name, idx) => {
  const searchFunction = idx !== 0 ? null : (helper) => {
    indexes.forEach((algoliaIndex, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        return;
      }

      algoliaIndex.helper.setQuery(helper.state.query).search()
    });

    helper.search();
  };

  return instantsearch({
    indexName: name,
    searchFunction,
    searchClient
  })
});


indexes[0].addWidget(instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
  container: '.search-box'
}));
indexes[0].addWidget(instantsearch.widgets.hits({
  container: '.hits-1'
}));
indexes[1].addWidget(instantsearch.widgets.hits({
  container: '.hits-2'
}));


for (var i = indexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  indexes[i].start();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/algoliasearch@3.32.1/dist/algoliasearchLite.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/instantsearch.js@3.2.0"></script>
<div class="search-box"></div>

<h1>First index</h1>
<div class="hits-1"></div>

<h1>Second index</h1>
<div class="hits-2"></div>
```

It's basically what you're doing, but the `searchFunction` is passed directly to the `instantsearch` initialization function, only for the first (main) index.

Note that because calling `start` on an instantsearch instance will immediately call `search` and hence the `searchFunction`, you have to start the main instance last so that `helper` exists on the other instances.

Comment: Nice - I implemented the same idea!